# Socket Binding Confusion

Tags: python, sockets

I've created a host / client application using my IPv4 address but now on want to create the same application with except I want it to be able to connect with clients on different networks. I thought that I'd bind the server to my public IP address but that gave me this error: `[WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context` What IP should I use to bind my server and connect remote clients to?

```
# host = public ip address. Took out just for safety concerns but on my 
# machine the actually ip is there
port = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
print("Server @ " + host + " awaiting connections on port " + str(port))
s.listen(1)
while True:
    client, address = s.accept()
    print("Connected with " + str(address))
    data = client.recv(1024)
    print(str(address) + " name is " + data.decode("utf-8"))
    if not data:
        break
s.close()
```

Comment: I guess you use a router? You need to setup NAT in this case and bind the programm to your internal network ip address.

Comment: Can we see the code please

Answer (score 0):

You program has to bind to an IP address that's assigned to the machine it's running on.  If you're behind a firewall, you'll need the firewall to forward traffic to that IP.

Public IP: 1.1.1.1

Computer IP: 2.2.2.2

Program binds to 2.2.2.2, clients connect to 1.1.1.1 (router/firewall forwards traffic from the public 1.1.1.1 to the private 2.2.2.2).